# Quotes as signatures in Gmail using Evernote

Tags: gmail, evernote

Long ago, I used to store my favorites quotes in a [.sig file](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/sig) that I would send as signatures in emails. I now want to integrate the quotes into my Gmail messages but I'm not sure of how to go about this.

If I was using something like Evernote would it be possible to have tagging, import/export from/to .sgi file and ultimately integrate those quotes in my GMail email signatures?

Comment: Hijacked this question to fit the answer otherwise as it was it would be not constructive and voted to close.

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise Unfortunatly I don't find that hijacking really useful, as it would lead anwserers towards the Evernote direction (which is exactly what jsut happened). I would personnally have prefered a kind of web service (in it's most restful way).

Comment: The Evernote answer came in before the edit. Otherwise you are just shopping and those type of questions are off topic across the network

Comment: Feel free to revert but know you risk the chance of this question being closed, so edit wisely. In its current form it is on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to solve this problem, using a combination of Evernote and the Wisestamp browser extension (available for both Firefox and Chrome). The features needed are available in the free versions of these tools.

Evernote allows you to create a public notebook. That notebook comes with an [RSS feed](https://support.evernote.com/link/portal/16051/16058/Article/2181/Accessing-RSS-Feeds-for-Public-Notebooks). You can also use Evernote's tags to organize your quotes, but I don't know if those tags will be accessible in any way in the RSS feed.

Then, you can use [Wisestamp's RSS App](http://wisestamp.com/goodies/how-to/how-to-add-rss-feeds-to-email-signatures/) to add the latest quote to your Gmail signature. I don't think this gives you a way to cycle or randomize the quotes though.